# Paramiko Threading paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Incompatible version (1.5 instead of 2.0)

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, paramiko, cisco

```
def trylogin(ipaddress):
  global user, passwd
  vmchannel = vmtransport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)
  jhost = paramiko.SSHClient()
  jhost.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
  jhost.connect(line, username=user, password=passwd, sock=vmchannel,)

vm = paramiko.SSHClient()
vm.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
vm.connect('57.255.35.71', username='xxxx', password='xxxx')
vmtransport = vm.get_transport()
local_addr = ('57.255.35.71', 22)
dest_addr = (IP, 22)
threading.Thread(target=trylogin, args=(IP,)).start()
```

while running the above code using thread to loop on multiple devices IP, it show the following Exception

```
Exception: Incompatible version (1.5 instead of 2.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mostafa.katary\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1856, in run
    self._check_banner()
  File "C:\Users\mostafa.katary\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2032, in _check_banner
    raise SSHException(msg.format(version))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Incompatible version (1.5 instead of 2.0)
```

but devices already using SSH version 2.0, this code runs correctly if either running on single IP or not using threads at all.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You seem to be setting port forwarding in a way that makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I am trying to access multiple Cisco switch through a jump server and execute similar commands on all switches using threads

Answer (score 0):

> Incompatible version (1.5 instead of 2.0)

That error message means the remote server announced that it implements SSH version 1.5. Paramiko requires version 2.0.

I'm guessing the remote system is a cisco device of some kind? You should investigate reconfiguring the device to use SSH version 2. I randomly found [this page](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960x/software/15-0_2_EX/security/configuration_guide/b_sec_152ex_2960-x_cg/b_sec_152ex_2960-x_cg_chapter_01001.html#d43017e591a1635) describing the command ("ip ssh version [1 | 2]") for configuring one of their systems. I have no idea whether the same command would apply to your system.

Note that Paramiko has a [FAQ section](http://www.paramiko.org/faq.html#paramiko-doesn-t-work-with-my-cisco-windows-or-other-non-unix-system) indicating they don't support atypical SSH servers including Cisco devices. You may continue to have problems getting Paramiko to work with the device even after reconfiguring it.

Comment: remote system is Cisco devices and they are configured to allow ssh 2.0, if I path only 1 device through thread it works, but not working if multiple devices